# Can I add this feature to Square Register: Assign some customers to tables?

Tags: mobile, payment, square

In iOS I would like to be able to add on a feature to square register in which I can assign some receipts (i.e., orders) to the table where the customer is sitting at. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Square is not an open source app so you probably can't add the feature.